# How to auto populate the address in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, recursion, iteration

This is the json object I have

```
[
  {
    "person": "abc",
    "city": "united states",
    "facebooklink": "link",
    "united states": [
      {
        "person": "cdf",
        "city": "ohio",
        "facebooklink": "link",
        "ohio": [
          {
            "person": "efg",
            "city": "clevland",
            "facebooklink": "link",
            "clevland": [
              {
                "person": "jkl",
                "city": "Street A",
                "facebooklink": "link",
                "Street A": [
                  {
                    "person": "jkl",
                    "city": "House 1",
                    "facebooklink": "link"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "person": "ghi",
            "city": "columbus",
            "facebooklink": "link"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "person": "abc",
        "city": "washington",
        "facebooklink": "link"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to create the below json adding address fields dynamically to the json.

```
[
  {
    "person": "abc",
    "city": "united states",
    "facebooklink": "link",
    "address": "united states",
    "united states": [
      {
        "person": "cdf",
        "city": "ohio",
        "facebooklink": "link",
        "address": "united states/ohio",
        "ohio": [
          {
            "person": "efg",
            "city": "clevland",
            "facebooklink": "link",
            "address": "united states/ohio/clevland",
            "clevland": [
              {
                "person": "jkl",
                "city": "Street A",
                "facebooklink": "link",
                "address": "united states/ohio/clevland/Street A",
                "Street A": [
                  {
                    "person": "jkl",
                    "city": "House 1",
                    "facebooklink": "link",
                    "address": "united states/ohio/clevland/Street A/House 1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "person": "ghi",
            "city": "columbus",
            "facebooklink": "link",
            "address": "united states/ohio/columbus"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "person": "abc",
        "city": "washington",
        "facebooklink": "link",
        "address": "united states/washington"
      }
    ]
  }
]
``

How can I achieve this in Python.
```

Comment: you can recursively traverse JSON structure and update the "address" field based on the hierarchy of the elements.

Comment: the json fields are auto generative of the values it holds; how can I traverse with dynamic json keys. Thanks @Daqs

Comment: question seems more clear. nice now.

Comment: let me try the answer. :)

Comment: This JSON looks really strangly nested, is this _actually_ your JSON or did you just make something up for the purpose of writing a post? (which is fine, as long as it represents the actual JSON you're working with, which ... I kinda doubt in this case, it feels like the real JSON would be just a flat array of person objects. People why would you nest people?)

Comment: It is an example but depicts the usual use case I have. @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Comment: And every person has a _different_ property name for nesting? Because if so: where are you getting this JSON from? Because that should get fixed first (e.g. by making sure every person object has a property called `location` instead of 20 different objects having 20 different keys for what is really just the same thing)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am sure the input data is complicated, but I have no command on it. but the gist is that the json address field needs to be populated according to the value of city in the parent json.

Comment: Right, but the problem here is that every "person" object has a _different_ nesting property which means you can't write code that you know will work. Even if you think you've written all possible property names, _you don't know whether you did_. At the very least, you're going to have to update your post with the list of every single property name that you know is currently used for nesting. Or, alternatively, you need to be able to _guarantee_ that there is only ever a single property with an array value. Which, again, you can't if you don't control the source of this data.

Comment: (Essentially: if we were to write code here, we have to make assumptions _that we know will be wrong_ in the absence of API docs that tell us what properties we can rely on. And we know that any code we try to write here is guaranteed to not work with future data. You're currently in a situation where the only code we can write is explicitly bugged code. Which is worse than not writing any code at all)

Comment: let me know if my below code helps? is that you are expecting? @Tanu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my best to solve. see if this helps.
wrote code with short json. but you can use complete nested json as input.

```
# import json

given_data = [
  {
    "person": "abc",
    "city": "united states",
    "facebooklink": "link",
    "united states": [
      {
        "person": "cdf",
        "city": "ohio",
        "facebooklink": "link"
      },
      {
        "person": "abc",
        "city": "washington",
        "facebooklink": "link"
      }
    ]
  }
]

PARENT_TOP = ""
city = "city"
address = 'address'

def update_address(parent_node, my_path=PARENT_TOP):
    if isinstance(parent_node, list):
        for child_node in parent_node:
            if isinstance(child_node, dict):
                city = child_node.get("city")
                new_path = f"{my_path}/{city}" if my_path else city
                child_node[address] = new_path
                grand_child = child_node.get(city)
                update_address(grand_child, new_path)
    elif isinstance(parent_node, dict):
        city = parent_node.get("city")
        new_path = f"{my_path}/{city}" if my_path else city
        parent_node[address] = new_path
        child = parent_node.get(city)
        update_address(child, new_path)
    else:
        pass

    return parent_node

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_address(given_data)
    # output = json.dumps(json.loads(str(given_data)), indent=2)
    print(given_data)
```

Comment: global city="city", seems not required.

Comment: @tanu this should help you. if you dont want to spoil the original data, then copy.deepcopy use it. and pass the deepcopied object and then continue with that object for address population.

Comment: i wrote code with short json. but you can use complete nested json as input.

Comment: please accept if my answer is good for you.